# did I mess up with multiple certificates?

Tags: active-directory, certificate, alfresco

I'm quite confused :S

scenario:
I m trying to add a certificate to my domain serverName. com.
I create a active directory sercer (DC) with ad.servername. com and cms.servername. com for Alfresco page.

and as far as I know, because it's alfresco bundle, it already has a tomcat with java and a Alfresco certificate configured (expire 2112).

then i generated my own .cer with microsoft certificate services with "servername. com" and imported to my java keystore (alfresco/java/jre/lib/security/cacert) expires 2014

later I decide to try a free trial third-party CA startssl. com and I generated for "servername. com" but they asked me to put an alternative, so I put cms.servername.com and I also imported to my alfresco/java key store (expire 2013)

now, whenever I put `https://servername:8443/myApp` or `https://cms.servername:8443` browser shows using Alfresco certificate. did I mess up with certificates or java or something is just selecting the older expiring date certificate to use?

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you put the right certificates and keys etc. in the right directory?

Like alf_data/keystore and in the tomcat config the 8443 points to the alfresco keys.